# System running in low graphics mode?

Tags: 12.10, boot, graphics

When I try to start up Ubuntu it is saying that my system is running in low graphics mode. It hasn't happened before, I have been able to use it before until I deleted games and tried to start it up again when this error came up. I tried to use it is the low graphics mode and sign in, but it wont sign in. Please help!!!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/141606/44179

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/218095/7035